# Problems compiling the Awesome 6 Pro font for the Mediawiki project

Tags: php, sass, font-awesome, mediawiki

I have been assigned a new project. This is a Mediawiki project. Now I am a bit overwhelmed with the update to Font Awesome 6. Some icons are not displayed on the website. I have found the place in the source code that is causing problems. The identified code in the source code is also too long to post, so I'll post a picture of it:

[image]

If I remove these as a test, the icons work. In my main.scss:

```
$fontAwesomeFont:'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
@import 'variables';
@import 'sp-sass/scss/style';

@import 'glyphicons/glyphicons/glyphicons';
@import 'glyphicons/halflings/glyphicons-halflings';
@import 'spicons';

@import 'modules/sidebar';
@import 'wiki';
@import 'modules/content';
@import 'modules/searchForm';

@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/duotone';
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/brands';
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/light';
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/regular';
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/solid';
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/v4-shims';
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome';
```

I found out that this import

```
@import 'fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome';
```

contains the code. If I remove this import, however, the other icons also disappear. I am slowly at a loss as to what the problem could be and I don't know where to start looking for it.
Could someone perhaps help me further.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It is the compiler. This has packed 3 icons, which represent special characters such as curly brackets, as such special characters in the Css file. As a result, the css file contained special characters that did not belong there. Maybe this helps someone.